# Two transition time for two different carousel in a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For my website in a page has two different bootstrap carousels. Each should have the its own transition speed.After a long try i found a way out via javascript

```
document.getElementById("image1").style.cssText="position: relative;-webkit-transition: 5s ease-in-out left;-moz-transition: 5s ease-in-out left;-o-transition: 5s ease-in-out left;transition: 5s ease-in-out left;";
```

for html

```
<div id="carouseltheme" class="carousel slide">
   <div class="carousel-inner" style="height:280px;margin-left:0em;">
       <div id="image1" class=" active item">
          <div class="row-fluid">
              <div class="span12" style="margin-top:1em;margin-left:5.5em">
                "inner-carousel"
              </div>
          </div>                   
       </div>
       <div id="image1" class="item">
          <div class="row-fluid">
              <div class="span12" style="margin-top:1em;margin-left:5.5em">
                  "inner-carousel"                
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

the transition speed decreased but the slide is not consistent. 
please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Very simple to do. Add as many carousels as you want and make sure that the ID is unique for each.Then, use jQuery and set the intervals for each. The independent ID's will also allow you to apply CSS for each as you see fit.

```
$('#carouseltheme').carousel({
    interval: 600
})
$('#carouseltheme2').carousel({
    interval: 1500
})
$('#carouseltheme3').carousel({
    interval: 2000
})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i meant to decrease transition sliding speed not delay between transition